# how would you write this sql to delete if either of two fields are in a set of values

Tags: sql, subquery

### **Background:**

---

i have 2 tables:

**Components:** (id, name)

**Dependencies:** (id, hasaComponentId, isaComponentId)

in this case the **hasaComponentId** and **isaComponentId** are both foreign keys into the components table joined by components.**id**

### Question

---

i have a set of Ids that the user selects.  I want a sql query that will delete records from the dependencies tables where any of the ids in my list of ids is either in the **hasaComponentId** field or the **isaComponentId** field.

what is the best sql for this action?

Comment: What is the data type for the other set of Id's, is it a comma seperated string variable by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM Dependencies WHERE hasaComponentId In (YOUR OTHER QUERY);
DELETE FROM Dependencies WHERE isaComponentId  In (YOUR OTHER QUERY);
```

OR

```
DELETE FROM Dependencies WHERE hasaComponentId In (YOUR OTHER QUERY) OR 
                               isaComponentId  In (YOUR OTHER QUERY);
```

Comment: I'd use EXISTs, but otherwise this would do it

Comment: what would be in (YOUR OTHER QUERY) . . i just have a list of ids coming from another source.  i have updated the question to clarify that

Comment: If they came from another query, like (SELECT X FROM Y), put that query in braces.

Comment: gotcha . . in this case its not from another query but out of curiosity, it would dynamically know that the result of the select query is a list of single fields ?

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE Dependencies
FROM Dependencies d, Components c
WHERE
 (  
  (c.id=d.hasaComponentID and d.isaComponentID is null)
  OR
  (c.id=d.isaComponentID and d.hasaComponentID is null)
 )
     AND c.id IN (1,2,3,5)
```

Not tested, but looks right. Make sure you perform a `SELECT` first!

Comment: Not sure why you're getting that. Also - edited for null check.